# Push and Pop Matrix

Tags: opengl

```
void display(void){
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    draw_square();
    glPushMatrix();

    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glTranslatef(-0.6, 0.6, 0.0);
    draw_square();

    glPopMatrix();
    //glPushMatrix();

    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glTranslatef(0.6, 0.6, 0.0);
    glRotatef(45, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    draw_square();

    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glScalef(1.2, 1.2, 1.0);
    glTranslatef(-0.7, -0.7, 0.0);
    draw_square();

    glPopMatrix();

    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0); //draw yellow box
    glTranslatef(-0.6, -0.6, 0.0);
    glScalef(1.2, 1.2, 1.0);
    draw_square();

    glFlush();
}
```

If I don't use the `glPushMatrix`(under the `glPopMatrix`), the yellow box at the bottom is not drawn. As I know, glPopMatrix() loads the last saved glPushMatrix() but I wonder why does it need to call `glPushMatrix` twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why does it need to call `glPushMatrix` twice.

Because it calls `glPopMatrix` twice. For every push, there should be a pop. That's [how a stack works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)).

`glPopMatrix` does not merely "loads the last saved glPushMatrix()"; it pops a stack of matrices. When you pop an element from a stack, it is *removed* from the stack. So the matrix that `glPopMatrix` "loads" is no longer exists on the stack. So if you want to preserve it, you have to push it back onto the stack.